# Nested grids with two tables

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, grid-layout

Imagine the following bootstrap grid layout. The main grid of 8:4.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The content data can be adjusted by the user. He/She can put the content either in the larger column or in the smaller one.

For instance two tables.

```
<div class="row">
    <div>
        <table>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div>
        <table>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

If the two tables will be placed in the larger column they should be side by side until a certain breakpoint is met, after which they should be one above the other.

If the two tables will be placed in the smaller column they should be always one above the other as the column is too small to display the tables side by side.

How could this be achieved? Is it possible with just CSS?

Further, if the layout gets too small, the two columns should be placed one above the other. This is reached by the "col-md-" classes. But if the user places to tables in the smaller column and the "md" breakpoint is reached the space will be large enough to display the tables side by side. Is this possible or will I have to live with some minor discrepancies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this nesting is easily possible using native Bootstrap 4 classes alone.

You simply put row-column pairs into a column of your choice like so:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 mb-3">
            <p>wide column</p>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">table 1 goes here</div>
                <div class="col-md-6">table 2 goes here</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p>narrow column</p>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-12 col-lg-6">table 3 goes here</div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-12 col-lg-6">table 4 goes here</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

That code will produce the exact behavior you described. On screens smaller than `md` they will all stack up on top of each other. Otherwise, both tables will be next to each other taking up 50% of space (6 units out of 12) in their corresponding parent column.

And if you determine that at the `sm` breakpoint, for example, there's still enough space for 2 tables side by side, then you could change the classes for the inner columns to something like `col-sm-6`. Then they'd sit side by side at that breakpoint.

Just remember that when nesting (or even in general) you always have row-column pairs i.e. a row always needs at least one column inside. Otherwise, you'd get in trouble with the layout.

Comment: Let my try again to explain, what I'm trying to achive.

If size of screen becomes smaller than 992 pixel the large breakpoint (lg) is reached, so the tables in the right column should be one above the other (if larger than 992 => side by side in right column). If the md-breakpoint is reached at 768 pixel the right column column moves under the left one (only one column left on main grid), but the tables should be placed again side by side, as there is enough space in the remaining column. If the small breakpoint is reached tables should wrap one above the other.

Comment: It was a bit hard to understand because you seem to misunderstand how the breakpoints actually work. They work the other way around as opposed to how you think they do. Bootstrap 4 is mobile-first, so everything starts at the smallest screen size and each breakpoint expands that. So, it's going up and not down. But I hope I managed to grasp what you meant. Check my updated code snippet.

Comment: P.S. You didn't say anything about the wide/left column. So, I assume that was OK.